# Animate element with smooth fade-in on appearance, but instantly hide on disappearance

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I've got an element with `opacity: 0`.

When a certain selector matches, I would like `opcacity` to smoothly transition to `1`.

When that selector no longer matches, I would like `opacity` to instantly revert to `0`.

How do I do that?

PS No JS, of course.

```css
.the {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid deepskyblue;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input:checked ~ .the {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  Show element
  
  <span class="the">
    I'm the element to animate!
  </span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `transition` to the `:checked` rule:

```css
.the {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid deepskyblue;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input:checked ~ .the {
  transition: opacity .5s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  Show element
  
  <span class="the">
    I'm the element to animate!
  </span>
</label>
```